# Ag-grid editing seems to not respect rowHeight when editing fullRow

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, editing

I am working with ag-gird and vanilla JS.  I have fullRowEditing turned on and I have added a 'getRowHeight' function to my gridOptions.  However, when I select a row to edit, the row height cramps down to show only 1 row.  Is there a way to change the row height for the editing?

Using ag-grid 20.0.0 and vanilla javascript.

I've already tried the silly stuff....

```
getRowHeight : {
    return 300;
},
getEditingRowHeight : {
   ///doesn't work -- various permutations of getEditxxxRowHeight
   return 400;
}
```

I have put in a custom div control that just puts in a div with 100% height and width and is colored Blue.

```
function DivComponent() {}

CustomControlComponent.prototype.init = function (params) {
    var template = "<div style='width: 100%, height: 72px, color: blue, border-color: blue'></div>";
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.innerHTML = template;
    .....
}

.....  other normal stuff ....
```

When I click on the row, it fires the editing events.  Then my Div is shortened to be only 1 line high.  When I am not editing, the control is fine.  But the editing causes all the controls to crunch, but not the row.  So you end up like this:

Not editing:

```
|  Column |   Column Div   |
-----------------------------
|  1      ||##############||
|         ||##############||
|         ||##############||
|         ||##############||
|         ||##############||
-----------------------------
```

Editing:

```
|  Column |   Column Div   |
-----------------------------
|  1      ||##############||
|         |                |
|         |                |
|         |                |
|         |                |
-----------------------------
```

How do I get the editing to spread out as much as the normal row height?  The getRowHeight() doesn't get fired for editing and the height is right now being determined by the CSS

.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell-inline-editing (28px).

How do I get that 28px to reflect my set value of my height?

Edited to add:

My DIV control is ultimately going to be variable height.  So, I cannot use a blanket CSS (that I know of?).  Row 1 might be 72px and row 2 might be 36 px.  I've tried using autoHeight and not.  It appears to be okay for just display, but not for editing.

Comment: have you tried resetting the css somewhere yourself? like `.ag-cell-inline-editing {row-height: 72px!important;}`

Comment: @LShapz - I'll edit my question, but that is a good point.  Ordinarily, that would be right, but my Div is ultimately going to be adjustable in height.  So, just a blanket 72px isn't going to always work.